# Get record with max id, using Hibernate Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

Using [Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/orm/)'s  [Criteria API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html), I want to select the record within a table with the maximum value for a given column.

I tried to use [Projections](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html), [creating an alias](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#createAlias(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) for `max(colunName)`, then using it in [`restrictions.eq()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#eq(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object)), but it keeps telling me "*invalid number*".

What's the correct way to do that with Hibernate?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use a `DetachedCriteria` to express a subquery, something like this:

```
DetachedCriteria maxId = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Foo.class)
    .setProjection( Projections.max("id") );
session.createCriteria(Foo.class)
    .add( Property.forName("id").eq(maxId) )
    .list();
```

#### References

- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [15.8. Detached queries and subqueries](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries)

Comment: i used it, but the something am not happy with is that: it need to run two queries, thanks again man

Comment: @AmrFaisal See my answer below on how to do this with one single query.

Answer (score 25):

I found that using `addOrder` and `setMaxResults` together worked for me.

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Thingy.class);
c.addOrder(Order.desc("id"));
c.setMaxResults(1);
return (Thingy)c.uniqueResult();
```

Using the MySQL dialect, this generates a SQL prepared statement about like this (snipping out some of the fields):

```
select this_.id ... from Thingy this_ order by this_.id desc limit ?
```

I am not sure if this solution would be effective for dialects other than MySQL.

Comment: It should be used with caution, because `order by` with `limit` is generally [slower](http://stackoverflow.com/a/426785/1251549) then `max`/`min` sql statements.

Answer (score 6):

Use

```
addOrder(Order.desc("id"))
```

and fetch just the first result :)

Comment: this is bad because you bring the entire list form the database then you discard every other records. Would not be very good in the case you have a huge table!

Comment: No, I said fetch the first, this would be something like "SELECT ... LIMIT 1" or something (sorry, haven't used hibernate in a long while now).  What you're saying is fetching several, and just using the first; they're different things.

Answer (score 4):

HQL:

```
from Person where person.id = (select max(id) from Person)
```

Untested. Your database needs to understand subselects in the where clause.

Too lazy to find out if/how such a subselect can be expressed with the criteria api. Of course, you could do two queries: First fetch the max id, then the entity with that id.

Comment: You are great man, i did use the second option, using two queries, but i was searching if it could be done using criteria api :)

Answer (score 0):

The cleaner solution would also be :

```
DetachedCriteria criteria = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Foo.class).setProjection(Projections.max("id"));
Foo fooObj =(Foo) criteria.getExecutableCriteria(getCurrentSession()).list().get(0);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    Date maxDateFromDB = null;
    Session session = (Session) entityManager.getDelegate();
//Register is and Entity and assume maxDateFromDB is a column.
//Status is another entity with Enum Applied.
//Code is the Parameter for One to One Relation between Register and Profile entity.
    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Register.class).setProjection(Projections.max("maxDateFromDB") )
    .add(Restrictions.eq("status.id", Status.Name.APPLIED.instance().getId()));
    if(code != null && code > 0) {
        criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("profile.id", code));
    }
    List<Date> list = criteria.list();

    if(!CollectionUtils.isEmpty(list)){
        maxDateFromDB = list.get(0);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To do it entirely with Detached Criteria (because I like to construct the detached criteria without a session)

```
DetachedCriteria maxQuery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Foo.class)
    .setProjection( Projections.max("id") );
DetachedCriteria recordQuery = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Foo.class)
    .add(Property.forName("id").eq(maxId) );
```

Answer (score -2):

For the `max()` function in hibernate:

```
criteria.setProjection(Projections.max("e.encounterId"));
```

Comment: I think this only returns the encounterId instead of the record object.