# Hibernate Criteria API for filtering a table rows by min value of its column

Tags: hibernate

How can we implement the following query using Hibernate criteria api

```
select * from User where date = select min(date) from User
```

where `User` have a column named `date`

Comment: duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900105/get-record-with-max-id-using-hibernate

Answer (score 0):

You have the Projections class for that which help for all aggregate/groupby stuff.
http://www.163jsp.com/help/hibernate32api/org/hibernate/criterion/Projections.html