# How can I get one database entry with max value using hibernate criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-criteria

If I have a class called Person as

```
public class Person{
  private int id;
  private int age;
}
```

How can I get the person object with max age?

when I use criteria.setProjection(Projections.max("age) ), it will return me the max age, and then I should find the entry of the person with this age.

Can I skip find the max age? And get the person with max age directly. It may looks like,

```
person = criteria.somehow.setProjection().somehow.setMaxResults(1).uniqueResult();
```

I'm trying find out the way to do this, because I concerned if I do twice search in hibernate, it will waste my performance time.

Comment: Seems to me this is duplicate of [Get record with max id, using Hibernate Criteria](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900105/get-record-with-max-id-using-hibernate-criteria).

Comment: I'd like to get Person object with max age

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following code :

```
Criteria cr = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
cr.setProjection(Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.max("age")));
```

If above does not work you can do this :

```
 Person p= (Person) session.createCriteria(Person.class)
.addOrder(Order.desc("age"))
.setMaxResults(1)
.uniqueResult();
```