# Hibernate: ClassCast Exception

Tags: java, hibernate

I am trying to fetch the `FileRepository` row with maximum version for a particular fileId. But following exception is thrown:

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.xxx.xxx.xxx.FileRepository

```
fileRepo = (FileRepository)session.createCriteria(FileRepository.class,"fileRepository")
                   .createAlias("fileRepository.file", "file")
                   .add(Restrictions.eq("file.fileId", file.getFileId()))
                   .setProjection(Projections.max("version")).uniqueResult();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
.setProjection(Projections.max("version")).uniqueResult();
```

Projection means receiving particular column values instead of rows.

If you see this making returning the ciriteria only version number which is an `Int`. 
Hence the error.

Either remove this projection or receive an int.

Comment: Thanks, So, How do I get a row with maximum version  with hibernate criteria?

Comment: @Forkmohit Instead of projection, add restriction for the same :)

Comment: found answer, with detachedcriteria. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3900105/get-record-with-max-id-using-hibernate-criteria