# How do I find the largest value in a column in postgres sql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, max

For example:

```
name | weight
jon    100    
jane   120    
joe    130
```

How do I only return the name of the person with the largest weight?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use this:

```
select name
from tbl
where weight = (select max(weight) from tbl)
```

Comment: wow, how silly of me not to think of using a nested query! thanks!

Comment: Depending on the number of rows with values of "weight" equal to the maximum value, this may return more than one name. Just FYI.

Comment: How do you make it return only one of the rows with the max value (doesn't matter how it chooses)?

Comment: select **top 1** name

from tbl

where weight = (select max(weight) from tbl)

Answer (score 105):

```
SELECT name FROM tbl ORDER BY weight DESC LIMIT 1
```

Much more performant than the other answer and results in one row only.

Comment: Good answer. I also want to note that if weight have an index, sort will performed on index and will be faster.

Comment: Nice answer, however it won't return two results if two people have the same weight.

Comment: LIMIT 1 requires a full table scan. This is _not_ performant with lots of rows. Try running `EXPLAIN` on your queries.

Comment: If there is any NULL in weight, it returns NULL

Comment: Weights with NULL values can be filtered out by using WHERE: `SELECT name FROM tbl WHERE weight IS NOT NULL ORDER BY weight DESC LIMIT 1`.

Comment: @Standaa-RememberMonica: Simply change the `LIMIT` to whatever value you feel is appropriate, e.g.,  `SELECT name FROM tbl ORDER BY weight DESC LIMIT 10`.

Comment: sorry, very bad solution: what if you have two similar highest values?

Answer (score 7):

If you need to find multiple rows, e.g. date on which each person had maximum weight:

```
name | weight | day
don    110      1
don    120      20
don    110      30
joe    90       1
joe    80       15
joe    85       30
```

i.e. for "don" you want to get `"don | 120 | 20"` and for joe you want `"joe | 90 | 1"`, then you can write:

```
SELECT name, max(weight), (array_agg(day ORDER BY weight DESC))[1] FROM tbl GROUP BY name
```

Comment: this is most elegant solution !!

Answer (score 3):

**ORDER BY DESC puts rows with null values at the top.**

To avoid returning results corresponding to **null values**:

`SELECT name FROM tbl WHERE weight = (SELECT MAX(weight) FROM tbl);`

Note: This query will return multiple results if multiple people have a weight equal to the maximum weight. To grab just one, add `LIMIT 1` to the end of the query.

---

Acknowledgements and more information:

[Why do NULL values come first when ordering DESC in a PostgreSQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958679/why-do-null-values-come-first-when-ordering-desc-in-a-postgresql-query)

[MIN/MAX vs ORDER BY and LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426731/min-max-vs-order-by-and-limit/)

[Postgres MAX Function](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-max-function/)