# Why do NULL values come first when ordering DESC in a PostgreSQL query?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, null, sql-order-by

When would you ever want NULLS first when ordering a query descending or ascending?

In my opinion, the **vast majority** of the time the desired behavior whether sorting ascending or descending would be NULLS LAST. Instead, we should have to specify NULLS FIRST.

Comment: Supposedly the SQL standard doesn't specify how `NULL` should be ordered, so its up to the people that wrote it into Postgres: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_by

Comment: Why have you wanted nulls first?

Comment: @usr Can you explain how the question "Why do NULL values come first when ordering DESC in a PostgreSQL query?" is opinion based?

Comment: @Bryan I don't think it is universal that NULLs are always needed first or last. If NULLs are an important anomaly or missing data, you might like to show them to the use first. If they represent unimportant cases you want to show them last. It totally depends on the use case. (Funnily, your question contains the phrase "In my opinion" :) ).

Comment: If nulls are an important anomaly - sounds like an edge case.  My "description of the problem" contains "In my opinion", but the question does not.  While my description is opinion based, the question is not an "Opinion-based question".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Actually, with default sort order (`ASCENDING`) NULL values come *last*.

Logic dictates that the sort order be reversed with the `DESCENDING` keyword, so nulls come *first* in this case.

But you can choose which way you want it. See:

- [Use the `NULLS FIRST | LAST` clause.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9511492/939860)

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY)

> If `NULLS LAST` is specified, null values sort after all non-null
> values; if `NULLS FIRST` is specified, null values sort before all
> non-null values. If neither is specified, **the default behavior is
> `NULLS LAST` when `ASC` is specified or implied**, and `NULLS FIRST` when `DESC`
> is specified (thus, the default is to act as though nulls are larger
> than non-nulls). When `USING` is specified, the default nulls ordering
> depends on whether the operator is a less-than or greater-than operator.

Bold emphasis mine.

Comment: Yes, it is logical that descending should be the opposite of ascending.  At the same time, NULL values have "no value", therefore NULL values should never be at the top of any ordered list.

Comment: @Bryan: depends on what you're doing. Sometimes, it makes sense for them to go first. The real issue is how and where to place the null data in a btree index. In postgres, the decision was made to put them last in there, so a reversed index look up makes them show up first.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is because that's how the people who wrote Postgres designed it. [To quote](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/sql-select.html#SQL-ORDERBY):

> The null value sorts higher than any other value. In other words, with ascending sort order, null values sort at the end, and with descending sort order, null values sort at the beginning.

This assumes that you have specified an ORDER BY clause, if you haven't then the rows are returned randomly.

> If the ORDER BY clause is specified, the returned rows are sorted in the specified order. If ORDER BY is not given, the rows are returned in whatever order the system finds fastest to produce.

Comment: You are quoting the manual for the [very old and unsupported version 8.2](http://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/).