# PostgreSQL select master records and display details columns for specific record

Tags: sql, postgresql, subquery, greatest-n-per-group, master-detail

First I must apologize for bad topic text, but I don't have any better idea. Maybe because of that, I didn't find solution when searching the web.

I have 2 tables: master and details who of course has foreign key to master. I would like to get all rows and all fields from master and fields from details for specific record (let's say order of some column) for every row in master.

I tried like this:

```
SELECT master.id, master.title, temp2.master_id, temp2.datetime, temp2.title_details
FROM master
LEFT JOIN (SELECT master_id, datetime, title AS title_details FROM details ORDER BY datetime DESC) temp2 ON temp2.master_id=master.id

//and this:
SELECT master.id, master.title, 
(SELECT master_id, datetime, title AS title_details FROM details WHERE master.id=details.master_id ORDER BY datetime DESC) 
FROM master
//but of course: subquery must return only one column
```

But this is not working.

Example what I want to do:

```
Master:
id  title
1   test
2   blab
3   something

Details:
id  master_id   datetime    title
1   1           2004-...    t: 1.1
2   1           2005-...    t: 2.1
3   1           2006-...    t: 3.1
4   2           2004-...    t: 4.2
5   2           2005-...    t: 5.2
6   3           2006-...    t: 6.3  

Expected output:
id  title       datetime    title_details
1   test        2006-...        t: 3.1
2   blab        2005-...        t: 5.2
3   something   2006-...        t: 6.3
```

Because it is hard for me to explain what I need, here is the PHP code (from head) what I don't want to do:

```
$q = Database::$DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM master");
$q2 = Database::$DB->prepare("SELECT * FROM details WHERE master_id=? ORDER BY datetime DESC LIMIT 1");
$rows = $q->execute();
foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $q2->execute($row->id);
    $row->AdditionalFields = $q2->fetch();
}
```

In other words, I don't want to iterate through all master rows and select data for specific ONE record (last - ORDER BY datetime) in details.

I tried all different UNIONs, JOINS and SUBQUERIES, but without success.

**EDITED (comment on different answers):**

The actual queries are:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (todo_topics.id) todo_topics.id, todo_topics.user_id, users.username AS author, todo_topics.title, todo_topics.datetime_created, todo_topics.version, todo_topics.todo_status_id, todo_statuses.icon_image, 
    todo_topics.version_status_changed, todo_posts.text, u.username AS last_poster, todo_posts.user_id as last_poster_id
FROM todo_topics
LEFT JOIN todo_statuses ON todo_statuses.id = todo_topics.todo_status_id
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = todo_topics.user_id
LEFT JOIN todo_posts ON todo_topics.id=todo_posts.todo_topic_id
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = todo_posts.user_id
ORDER BY todo_topics.id, todo_posts.datetime_created  DESC
```

"Total runtime: 0.863 ms"

```
    SELECT
      todo_topics.id, todo_topics.user_id, users.username AS author, todo_topics.title, todo_topics.datetime_created, todo_topics.version, todo_topics.todo_status_id, todo_statuses.icon_image, 
        todo_topics.version_status_changed, todo_posts.text, u.username AS last_poster, todo_posts.user_id as last_poster_id
    FROM
      todo_topics
      LEFT JOIN todo_statuses ON todo_statuses.id = todo_topics.todo_status_id
    LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = todo_topics.user_id

    INNER JOIN
    (
      SELECT
        *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY todo_topic_id ORDER BY datetime_created DESC) AS ordinal
      FROM
        todo_posts
    )
      AS todo_posts
        ON todo_posts.todo_topic_id = todo_topics.id
    LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = todo_posts.user_id
    WHERE
      todo_posts.ordinal = 1
```

"Total runtime: 1.281 ms"

```
 SELECT
  todo_topics.id, todo_topics.user_id, users.username AS author, todo_topics.title, todo_topics.datetime_created, todo_topics.version, todo_topics.todo_status_id, todo_statuses.icon_image, 
    todo_topics.version_status_changed, todo_posts.text, u.username AS last_poster, todo_posts.user_id as last_poster_id
FROM
  todo_topics
LEFT JOIN todo_statuses ON todo_statuses.id = todo_topics.todo_status_id
LEFT JOIN users ON users.id = todo_topics.user_id
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    todo_topic_id,
    MAX(datetime_created)  AS max_datetime
  FROM
    todo_posts
  GROUP BY
    todo_topic_id
)
  AS details_lookup
    ON  details_lookup.todo_topic_id = todo_topics.id
INNER JOIN
  todo_posts
    ON  todo_posts.todo_topic_id = details_lookup.todo_topic_id
    AND todo_posts.datetime_created  = details_lookup.max_datetime
LEFT JOIN users u ON u.id = todo_posts.user_id
```

"Total runtime: 1.143 ms"

If someone want to know what this time means for specific hardware:

The database is experimental (a few records in each table - < 100) running on Windows 7 localhost, Intel I7 3,4GHz, 16GB ram, PostgreSQL 9.3.4 (default installation)

Comment: For a more meaningful test you'd need populated tables. And don't forget about indexes. Those get *much* more important when the tables grow. Follow the link in my answer for more about a fitting index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simpler with [`DISTINCT ON`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT):

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (m.id)
       m.*, d.datetime, d.title AS title_details
FROM   master m
LEFT   JOIN details d ON d.master_id = m.id
ORDER  BY m.id, d.datetime DESC;
```

Assuming `master.id` to be the primary key and `details.datetime` to be `NOT NULL`.
Detailed explanation:
[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)

Careful if `datetime` can be NULL. You probably want [`NULLS LAST`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958679/why-do-null-values-come-first-when-ordering-desc-in-a-postgresql-query/20959470#20959470) in that case.

Comment: I think you mean:

SELECT DISTINCT ON (m.id)
       m.*, d.datetime, d.title AS title_details
FROM   master m
LEFT   JOIN details d ON d.master_id = m.id
ORDER  BY m.id, d.datetime DESC

Why (if) is your solution better than @MatBailie

Comment: @Makla: Correct. Applied. The sort order depends on which row you want to pick. I see in your PHP code now: you want to sort by `datetime`. The example works either way. Why is it better? Shorter and faster. Just test with `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` to see for yourself, you don't have to take my word for it.

Comment: True, it is confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  master
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY master_id ORDER BY datetime DESC) AS ordinal
  FROM
    details
)
  AS details
    ON details.master_id = master.id
WHERE
  details.ordinal = 1
```

Or...

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  master
INNER JOIN
(
  SELECT
    master_id,
    MAX(datetime)  AS max_datetime
  FROM
    details
  GROUP BY
    master_id
)
  AS details_lookup
    ON  details_lookup.master_id = master.id
INNER JOIN
  details
    ON  details.master_id = details_lookup.master_id
    AND details.datetime  = details_lookup.max_datetime
```