# Combine the most recent entries from a number of tables

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, greatest-n-per-group, crosstab

I have a `master` table with a number of IDs in it:

```
ID  ...
0   ...
1   ...
```

And multiple tables (say `vtbl1`, `vtbl2`, `vtbl3`) with a foreign key to `master`, a timestamp and a value:

```
ID  Timestamp    Value
0   01/01/01..   2
1   01/01/02..   7
0   01/01/03..   5
```

I would like to get one or more entries for each `ID` in `master` with an entry (or null if no entries exist) containing the most recent entry in each `v...` table (grouped by timestamps):

```
ID  Timestamp    vtbl1.Value   vtbl2.Value   vtbl3.value
0   01/01/03..   5             2
0   01/01/01..                               4
1   01/01/02..   7             4             9
```

I'm sure this is fairly simple but my SQL is rusty and I've been going in circles. Any help would be appreciated.

#### Clarification

These values come from one or more sensors able to read one or more of the values. So the latest `value` in each value table for the `ID` is to be considered the current system state for that `ID`. If the timestamps match they are considered one update.

I need the minimal set of updates required for each `ID` to give a full data set for the current state.

Also the values can be of *different types*.

Comment: If you have multiple timestamps associated with the same `id` in the child tables, what determines the `max(timestamp)` to display in the results?  The max in one might not be the max in the other...

Comment: There may be multiple rows for each id. See ID 0 in the example.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, one option is to use conditional aggregation and `union all`:

```
select id, timestamp, 
       max(case when tbl = 'tbl1' then value end) t1value,
       max(case when tbl = 'tbl2' then value end) t2value,
       max(case when tbl = 'tbl3' then value end) t3value
from (
    select id, timestamp, value, 'tbl1' tbl
    from tbl1
    union all
    select id, timestamp, value, 'tbl2' tbl
    from tbl2
    union all
    select id, timestamp, value, 'tbl3' tbl
    from tbl3
) t
group by id, timestamp
```

---

Or if you have multiple records per `id` and you want the highest `value` per by `timestamp`, you can include `row_number()` in your subquery:

```
select id, timestamp, 
       max(case when tbl = 'tbl1' then value end) t1value,
       max(case when tbl = 'tbl2' then value end) t2value,
       max(case when tbl = 'tbl3' then value end) t3value
from (
    select id, timestamp, value, 'tbl1' tbl,
        row_number() over (partition by id order by timestamp desc) rn
    from tbl1
    union all
    select id, timestamp, value, 'tbl2' tbl,
        row_number() over (partition by id order by timestamp desc) rn
    from tbl2
    union all
    select id, timestamp, value, 'tbl3' tbl,
        row_number() over (partition by id order by timestamp desc) rn
    from tbl3
) t
where rn = 1
group by id, timestamp
```

This can get difficult though if max(timestamp) values aren't the same in each of the child tables.  Which do you `join` on at that point?

Comment: This will grab the highest `value` from each of the child tables rather than the `value` associated with the highest `timestamp` for each `id`

Comment: @BrianDeMilia -- I see your point and added an alternative issue.  We both might have a problem if this is the case though -- what determines the `max(timestamp)` from child tables to join on?  At this point, additional data with sample results would be needed for clarification.

Comment: I'll add some clarification to the question - give me a minute. The short version is I need the smallest number of rows to give a complete most recent dataset (a complete data set being at least one value for every value table that has an entry associated with the ID).

Comment: Agreed, it's unclear what timestamp he wants shown as he only has one timestamp column in his expected output, when there is likely a different timestamp on each table that is the highest for the given id. I could understand if he had shown 3 timestamp columns, in which case he'd want the timestamp that was associated with each of the 3 values.

Comment: Added clarification. I I want the timestamp associated with the updates. If there are multiple timestamps there should be multiple rows in the output. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

```
select m.*, v1.value as t1_val, v2.value as t2_val, v3.value as t3_val
  from master m
  left join (select x.*
               from vtbl1 x
               join (select id, max(timestamp) as last_ts
                      from vtbl1
                     group by id) y
                 on x.id = y.id
                and x.timestamp = y.last_ts) v1
    on m.id = v1.id
  left join (select x.*
               from vtbl2 x
               join (select id, max(timestamp) as last_ts
                      from vtbl2
                     group by id) y
                 on x.id = y.id
                and x.timestamp = y.last_ts) v2
    on m.id = v2.id
  left join (select x.*
               from vtbl3 x
               join (select id, max(timestamp) as last_ts
                      from vtbl3
                     group by id) y
                 on x.id = y.id
                and x.timestamp = y.last_ts) v3
    on m.id = v3.id
```

Answer (score 0):

The fastest query technique depends on the distribution of values. [`DISTINCT ON`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564) would be a simple solution in Postgres, ideal for just a few values per `id` in each child table. But guessing from your description I expect *many* rows per `id`, so I suggest a solution with `LATERAL` joins. Requires Postgres 9.3+:

- [Optimize GROUP BY query to retrieve latest record per user](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25536422/optimize-group-by-query-to-retrieve-latest-record-per-user/25536748#25536748)

One more complication for your already-not-so-simple case:

> Also the values can be of different types

### Alternative 1

Cast all values to [`text`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/datatype-character.html). Every data type can be cast to `text`.

#### Base query

```
SELECT m.id, v.timestamp, 1 AS tbl, v.value  -- simple int as table id
FROM   master m
     , LATERAL (
   SELECT timestamp, value::text  -- cast to text
   FROM   vtbl1
   WHERE  id = m.id  -- lateral reference
   ORDER  BY timestamp DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT  1
   ) v

UNION ALL
SELECT m.id, v.timestamp, 2 AS tbl, v.value  -- ascending without gaps
FROM   master m
     , LATERAL (
   SELECT timestamp, value::text
   FROM   vtbl2
   WHERE  id = m.id
   ORDER  BY timestamp DESC NULLS LAST
   LIMIT  1
   ) v

UNION ALL
SELECT m.id, v.timestamp, 3 AS tbl, value
FROM  ...
;
```

All you need for this to be fast is an index on `(id, timestamp)` for each child table. Best in this form (adding `value` is only useful if you get [index-only scans](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Index-only_scans) out of it):

```
CREATE INDEX vtbl1_combo_idx ON vtbl1 (id, timestamp DESC NULLS LAST, value)
```

#### 1a. Aggregate (pseudo-crosstab)

To format as desired use aggregate functions on `CASE` expressions in Postgres 9.3 or older (like [demonstrated by @sgeddes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29334272/939860)) or (better) the new aggregate `FILTER` clause in Postgres 9.4+:

- [How can I simplify this game statistics query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27136251/how-can-i-simplify-this-game-statistics-query/27141193#27141193)

```
SELECT id, timestamp
     , max(value) FILTER (WHERE tbl = 1) AS val1
     , max(value) FILTER (WHERE tbl = 2) AS val2
     , ...
FROM ( <query frm above> ) t
GROUP  BY 1, 2;
```

#### 1b. Crosstab

Actual cross tabulation (also called "pivot" in other RDBMS) should be considerably faster. You need the additional module [`tablefunc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/tablefunc.html) installed, instructions below.

The special difficulty here: we have a composite "row name" `(id, timestamp)`, but the function expects a *single* column as row name. So we substitute with `row_number()`, but do not display that surrogate key in the result:

```
SELECT id, timestamp, val1, val2, val3, ...
 -- normally SELECT * is enough; explicit list to filter rn
FROM  crosstab(
    $$
    SELECT row_number() OVER (ORDER BY id, timestamp DESC NULLS LAST) AS rn
         , id, timestamp, tbl, value
    FROM  ( <query from above> ) t
    ORDER  BY 1
    $$
  , 'SELECT generate_series(1,3)'  -- replace 3 with highest table nr.
    ) AS ct (
    rn int, id int, timestamp date
  , val1 text, val2 text, val3 text, ...);
```

Closely related:

- [Postgres - Transpose Rows to Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060256/postgres-transpose-rows-to-columns/23061730#23061730)

Relevant basics:

- [PostgreSQL Crosstab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3002499/postgresql-crosstab-query/11751905#11751905)
- [Pivot on Multiple Columns using Tablefunc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415446/pivot-on-multiple-columns-using-tablefunc/15421607#15421607)

### Alternative 2

Simple, but may be just as fast and preserves original data types:

```
SELECT id, timestamp
     , max(val1) AS val1, max(val2) AS val2, max(val3) AS val3, ...
FROM  (
   SELECT m.id, v.timestamp
        , v.value AS val1, NULL::int AS val2, NULL::numeric AS val3, ...   
          -- list all values with actual data type
   FROM   master m
        , LATERAL (
      SELECT timestamp, value
      FROM   vtbl1
      WHERE  id = m.id
      ORDER  BY timestamp DESC NULLS LAST
      LIMIT  1
      ) v

   UNION ALL
   SELECT m.id, v.timestamp
        , NULL, v.value, NULL, ...  -- column names & data types defined in first SELECT
   FROM   master m
        , LATERAL (
      SELECT timestamp, value
      FROM   vtbl2
      WHERE  id = m.id
      ORDER  BY timestamp DESC NULLS LAST
      LIMIT  1
      ) v

   UNION ALL
   SELECT m.id, v.timestamp
        , NULL, NULL, v.value, ...
   FROM  ...
   ) t
GROUP  BY 1, 2
ORDER  BY 1, 2;
```

Aside: Never use basic type names or [reserved words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) (in standard SQL) like `timestamp` as identifier.

Comment: Cheers. Will look at properly and test when I get back.