# PostgreSQL convert rows to columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

My current table is like below

```
AllotmentClass    Appro1    Appro2    Appro3   
        A           5000     4568      2453
        B           6000     4845      4568
        C           8592      454      5486
        D           4587     4895      4653
```

My required output is,

```
Measure     A      B      C       D
Appro1     5000   6000   8592    4587
Appro2     4568   4845    454    4895
Appro3     2453   4568   5486    4653
```

And this is static, not dynamic.

Comment: Why don't you do it client-side?

Comment: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060256/postgres-transpose-rows-to-columns)

Comment: Have you looked at the hundreds of questions [tagged with `postgresql` and `pivot`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+pivot) or [tagged with `postgresql` and `crosstab`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/postgresql+crosstab)?