# convert rows to columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I have a table called `event`. which is like :

```
user_id    feature_name  feature_value
   1          launced         yes
   1          voice_enabled   no
   1          trim_used       yes
   1          voice_enabled   yes
   1          trim_used       yes  
   2          launched         yes
   2          voice_enabled   no
   2          trim_used       no
   2          voice_enabled   yes
   2          zoom_used       yes
```

There are thousand of rows like this and In `feature_name` column there can   more features be added if any users would use it.

I have to convert this table in more meaningful format where each feature_name will be a separate column and  having the count of the feature used by a particular user.

So output table looks like:

```
user_id   launched  voice_enabled  trim_used  zoom_used
   1         1           1             2         0
   2         1           1             0         1
```

Any help would be much appreciated. I am using PostgreSQL.

Comment: You need new table or only processed them to utize

Comment: Both will be fine.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+rows+to+columns or https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+crosstab or https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[postgresql]+pivot

Answer (score -1):

You can very well use transpose for your use case.

Please see post below which explains it:

[Postgres - Transpose Rows to Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060256/postgres-transpose-rows-to-columns)