# Transpose rows into column in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, transpose

Here is my current PostgreSQL query:

```
 SELECT     
        c.ce_new_cat_short, 
        d.ver_desc_txt, 
        c.product_type, 
        round(sum(d.profit_amt/f.exch_rate)::numeric, 2) AS dp_dol, 
        sum(d.unit_qty) AS units
 FROM       
        ext_ce.gsam_v_data_detail as d
        LEFT JOIN
            (SELECT DISTINCT g.prmry_prfl_cd, g.wrkhrs_grp, g.brnd_fmly_desc_txt_adj FROM ext_ce.gsam_v_data_context AS g) AS vc
        ON vc.prmry_prfl_cd = d.prmry_prfl_cd,  
        ext_ce.gsam_data_context as c,
        ext_ce.info_fx_rates_v2 as f
 WHERE      
        c.product_type <> 'SALES AIDS'::text 
        AND c.cncpt_nr::numeric = d.prmry_prfl_cd
        AND f.offr_cmpgn_yr_nr = 2017
        AND d.mrkt_desc_txt = f.mrkt_desc_txt
 GROUP BY   
        c.ce_new_cat_short,  
        d.ver_desc_txt, 
        c.product_type;
```

I'm stuck trying to transpose `column ver_desc_txt`.

Here is my current output, alongside a desirable one.

[image: Current and desired output]

How can I adjust this query to get the desirable output?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Postgres - Transpose Rows to Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060256/postgres-transpose-rows-to-columns)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use FILTER clause to limit aggregate functions:

```
SELECT     
        c.ce_new_cat_short, 
        c.product_type, 
        round(sum(CASE WHEN d.ver_desc_txt = 'FINAL LEADER LIST' THEN d.profit_amt/f.exch_rate ELSE 0 END)::numeric, 2) AS dp_dol_FLL, 
        round(sum(CASE WHEN d.ver_desc_txt = 'BEST OFFICAL PROJECTION' THEN d.profit_amt/f.exch_rate ELSE 0 END)::numeric, 2) AS dp_dol_BOP, 
        sum(CASE WHEN d.ver_desc_txt = 'FINAL LEADER LIST' THEN d.unit_qty ELSE 0 END) AS units_FLL,
        sum(CASE WHEN d.ver_desc_txt = 'BEST OFFICAL PROJECTION' THEN d.unit_qty ELSE 0 END) AS units_BOP
 FROM       
        ext_ce.gsam_v_data_detail as d
        JOIN ext_ce.gsam_data_context as c
            ON (c.cncpt_nr::numeric = d.prmry_prfl_cd)
        JOIN ext_ce.info_fx_rates_v2 as f
            ON ( d.mrkt_desc_txt = f.mrkt_desc_txt)
        LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT g.prmry_prfl_cd, g.wrkhrs_grp, g.brnd_fmly_desc_txt_adj FROM ext_ce.gsam_v_data_context AS g) AS vc
            ON vc.prmry_prfl_cd = d.prmry_prfl_cd
 WHERE      
        c.product_type <> 'SALES AIDS'::text 
        AND f.offr_cmpgn_yr_nr = 2017
 GROUP BY   
        1, 2
```

Also I would recommend you to use JOIN form of join - it allows to be assured that all part of join is joined correctly.

## UPD:

For version 8.2.15 must use CASE WHERE instead FILTER

Comment: Sorry, because there are no structures and sample tables i can not test table. I remove one ',' and add one. Please try now

Comment: shouldn't be: FILTER (where d.ver_desc_txt = 'FINAL LEADER LIST') AS dp_dol_FLL,    ?

Comment: Now query improved. After `dp_dol_FLL` ',' must be, after  `ON vc.prmry_prfl_cd = d.prmry_prfl_cd` no.

Comment: hmm, still: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "d" line 4

Comment: Sorry, one more mistake - WHERE in FILTER clause

Comment: no problems, appreciate your efforts. Now I got this: ERROR:  filter clause specified, but round is not an aggregate function

Comment: fixed (run round on while clause)

Comment: Roman, thanks but : ERROR:  syntax error at or near "FILTER" line 4.

Comment: Which version of postgresql do you use?

Comment: 1.22.1 feb 2016. pg admin III

Comment: SELECT version();

Comment: 1.22.1 - it is pgadmin

Comment: 8.2.15 is this what U need?

Comment: Wow. It is very old. Few minutes.

Comment: Please try. But I would recommend to upgrade postgresql. 8.2.15 was released 2009-12-14. There are many advantages in 9.x versions.