# Transpose rows to columns in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot

I need to transform rows to columns with the corresponding values

I am new to Postgres, I have inserted the link to images of my table and how I need the Required result. I will really appreciate any suggestions or remarks to resolve it
enter image description here:

original table
[image]

required result
[image]

Comment: you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060256/postgres-transpose-rows-to-columns

Comment: my scenario is different, I need my row values to be column names which are not covered in this example. ex-  currently i have columns as submission id,question id,question type,answers. when I transpose it I want the question type to become different columns and contain answers as a value against it

Comment: 1.Please do not use images to describe your problem. You want us to help you. But now we cannot copy/paste your data. That creates a load more work for us. Furthermore, please simplify your problem. To describe your problem you do not need a bunch of unique ids, so much data sets and so on. 5 records with question_types and a simple integer id would be lovely.

Comment: 3. Concerning the problem: You want the values of question_type to be the columns. Are the values fixed or dynamic (in other words: Are there exactly these 8 values?)

Comment: i understad that using image is problem but i was not able to type in everything and was not able to add excel sheet for refrence thats why i went for image.I appreciate everyone helping out. though i was able to resolve the issue,here is the query i wrote :-

Comment: Your question is quite unclear. Your problem and desired output looks  same. It would better if you have described if more clearly along with clear and readable examples.

Answer (score 3):

In case that the columns stay the same, this is a simple pivot. This can be done by grouping and filtering the aggregates:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=f2a9b76114826275b44bfcaf4d392db8)

```
SELECT
    submission_id, question_id, question_type,
    MAX(answer) FILTER (WHERE question_type = 'A') AS answer_to_a,
    MAX(answer) FILTER (WHERE question_type = 'B') AS answer_to_b,
    MAX(answer) FILTER (WHERE question_type = 'C') AS answer_to_c
FROM
    questions
GROUP BY submission_id, question_id, question_type
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that using an image is a problem but I was not able to type in everything and was not able to add excel sheet f. I appreciate everyone helping out. though I was able to resolve the issue,

```sql
create view test3 as 
( SELECT
    *
FROM CROSSTAB (
    'SELECT
  entryid
, submissionid
, questionid
, questiontext
, questiontype
, answer    
     FROM test2
     ORDER BY 1;'
     , $$ VALUES ('CSAT'::TEXT), ('FACILITIES'::TEXT), ('NPS'::TEXT), ('SERVICES'::TEXT), ('FOOD_BEVERAGES'::TEXT) $$
) AS "ct" (
    "entryid" TEXT
    , "submissionid" TEXT
, "questionid" TEXT
, "questiontext" TEXT
    , "CSAT" TEXT
    , "FACILITIES" TEXT
    , "NPS" TEXT
, "SERVICES" TEXT
, "FOOD_BEVERAGES" TEXT
)
);
```