# Relating 5 fields with the same id to one table with the same single id using postgres/postgis

Tags: python, postgresql

I am simply trying to join 5 fields (different rows) with the same id to a single table with a matching single id using postgres/postgis/python.

The data looks like this:

[image]

and the table I am trying to join it to looks like this:

[image]

There is a similar thread that discusses this but I cannot figure out the logic to transfer all 5 data field row to one single row in the new table.
[Postgres - Transpose Rows to Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060256/postgres-transpose-rows-to-columns?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: Can you give the desired output for your given example? And please as formatted text, not as picture

Comment: Without desire output we can't help.    Show us db schema, sample data, current and expected output. 
 Please read [**How-to-Ask**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 
 And here is a great place to [**START**](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) to learn how improve your question quality and get better answers.

 [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

 Try create a sample in http://rextester.com