# postgres list rows of table as columns

Tags: sql, postgresql, dynamic, datatables, rows

i need your help for a pgsql request. i have in my db 2 tables: squads(name)
and account(account_name, score, squad_name). what i would like to do is to list all squad and for each squad, to get the score of each account.
So i have same number of column than accounts.
How can i do that ? knowing that accounts and squads can change often so it must be dynamic.

here is a result i would like to have: [query result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEI7c.png)

EDIT

as asked, here is a simple model of my db(i just have more evaluation types like email etc...).
[my model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zLBZP.png)

for exemple i do lots of evaluations of calls that employees take. an evaluation belongs to a squad and to an account. i join tables by the names of squad and account.
now i need to see the score of the evaluation(per squad and per account as described in the first picture). idealy columns are the accounts

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by dynamic? Have you tried equijoin to start with?

Comment: i mean dynamic because i don't want to write in the request all names of accounts. columns should be the result of :select * from accounts. i edited my question with a picture of what i would like to do. i tried different joins but without success.

Comment: Please also share the table definitions and also if any relationships between them and sample data in each of these tables.

Comment: question edited. thanks

Comment: Seems like you have to make a sort of dynamic sql which will transpose your accounts into columns. `crosstab` should [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23061730/599164)

Comment: two questions, (1) why doesn't your accounts table have account_name, if your squads table have squad_name? if call_evaluation has all the attributes, what purpose does the many to 1 relationship serve i.e. why would I join?