# transpose single row to column

Tags: sql, postgresql, unpivot

I have seen similar questions but the answers did not work for me, I would like to transpose the following table :

```
| 2017  | 2018  | 2019  | 2020  |
|------ |------ |------ |------ |
| 358   | 1300  | 973   | 101   |
```

And would like to get this table :

```
|       | Count     |
|------ |-------    |
| 2017  | 358       |
| 2018  | 1300      |
| 2019  | 973       |
| 2020  | 101       |
```

Comment: The general, easy way: UNION ALL.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060256/postgres-transpose-rows-to-columns

Comment: @jarlh: the "easy" way is to use a lateral join ;)

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, yes, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Use a lateral join:

```
select x.year, x.count
from the_table t
  cross join lateral (
      values ("2017", 2017), ("2018", 2018), ("2019", 2019), ("2020", 2020)
  ) as x(count, year)
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3b393210083fbbf2141a2478d7a81839)

Comment: It does not work for me. I got the error 
ERROR: column "2017" does not exist in t

Comment: @enriqueqs: well your sample data shows a column named `"2017"` - if you don't have that you should have shown us the **real** column names.

Comment: it came from  `sum(2017_values) as "2017" `

Comment: @enriqueqs: please edit your question and show us the complete query. With the current information in the question, this is the only answer that is possible to give.