# how to merge two rows in postgres using select

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that has rows that look like this

| Account | Currency | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | USD | 5 |
| 1 | EUR | 10 |
| 2 | USD | 8 |
| 3 | EUR | 4 |

Is there a way to do a select query so it would return something like

| Account | amount_usd | amount_eur |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 5 | 10 |
| 2 | 8 |  |
| 3 |  | 4 |

usd and eur are hardcoded, so i dont have to build the name from the column.

Comment: This is well explained in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060256/postgres-transpose-rows-to-columns

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Postgres - Transpose Rows to Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060256/postgres-transpose-rows-to-columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation which in Postgres uses `filter`:

```
select account,
       sum(amount) filter (where currency = 'USD') as usd_amount,
       sum(amount) filter (where currency = 'EUR') as eur_amount
from t
group by account;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use sum() with case when condition :

```
select account, sum(case when currency='USD' then amount end) Amount_USD,
sum(case when currency='EUR' then amount end) Amount_EUR
from myTable
Group by account
```