# Postgres Transpose Rows to Columns Based on Column Value

Tags: sql, postgresql, switch-statement, transpose, crosstab

I have the following `statement` table in Postgres:

```
stock |  year | statement    | amount           

ACME  | 2003  | Q1 Earnings  | 100
ACME  | 2003  | Q2 Earnings  | 200
ACME  | 2004  | Q2 Earnings  | 300
```

How do I make a new table with all of a year's 4 quarters on one row? And null values for missing statements.

```
stock | year | Q1 Earnings | Q2 Earnings | Q3 Earnings | Q4 Earnings 

ACME  | 2003 | 100         | 200         | Null        | Null
ACME  | 2004 | NULL        | 300         | Null        | Null
```

Found this answer: [Postgres - Transpose Rows to Columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23060256/postgres-transpose-rows-to-columns) but it doesn't show how to create and populate the new columns based on another value or deal with null values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you have a fixed 4 quarters per year which you want to display, use pivoting logic:

```sql
SELECT
    stock,
    year,
    MAX(amount) FILTER (WHERE statement = 'Q1 Earnings') AS "Q1 Earnings",
    MAX(amount) FILTER (WHERE statement = 'Q2 Earnings') AS "Q2 Earnings",
    MAX(amount) FILTER (WHERE statement = 'Q3 Earnings') AS "Q3 Earnings",
    MAX(amount) FILTER (WHERE statement = 'Q4 Earnings') AS "Q4 Earnings"
FROM statement
GROUP BY
    stock,
    year;
```

Comment: Thank you. Does this automatically take care of NULL values?

Comment: If a given stock and year have no data for a certain quarter, then the above would just report `NULL` in that case.  You may use `COALESCE` to display some backup value if you want.