# Optimizing window function in PostgreSQL to use index

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

I have a table in a PostgreSQL 9.2 DB, created and filled as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE foo( id integer, date date );

INSERT INTO foo
SELECT (id % 10) + 1, now() - (id % 50) * interval '1 day'
FROM generate_series(1, 100000) AS id;
```

Now, I need to find all pairs `(id, date)` such that the date is a maximum one among all pairs with the same `id`. The query is kind of well known and it's common to use the window function called `ROW_NUMBER()`

```
SELECT id, date
FROM (
    SELECT id, date, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC) rn
    FROM foo
) sbt
WHERE sbt.rn = 1;
```

Now, I ask for the plan of that query and figured out that the `WindowAgg` node requires a table to be sorted first.

```
Subquery Scan on sbt  (cost=11116.32..14366.32 rows=500 width=8) (actual time=71.650..127.809 rows=10 loops=1)
  Filter: (sbt.rn = 1)
  Rows Removed by Filter: 99990
    ->  WindowAgg  (cost=11116.32..13116.32 rows=100000 width=8) (actual time=71.644..122.476 rows=100000 loops=1)
          ->  Sort  (cost=11116.32..11366.32 rows=100000 width=8) (actual time=71.637..92.081 rows=100000 loops=1)
                Sort Key: foo.id, foo.date
                Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1752kB
                ->  Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..1443.00 rows=100000 width=8) (actual time=0.006..6.138 rows=100000 loops=1)
```

As expected, the sorting took the majority of the query execution time and it would definitely helpful to use `index`es.

So I create the `CREATE INDEX ON foo(id, date)` and expect that now it'll be use indexes. But it doesn't. I got the same plan with the `external merge` and even turning off the `sequential scan` wasn't useful. I just ended up with `Bitmap Index Scan`

```
->  Sort  (cost=12745.58..12995.58 rows=100000 width=8) (actual time=69.247..90.003 rows=100000 loops=1)
      Sort Key: foo.id, foo.date
      Sort Method: external merge  Disk: 1752kB
      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on foo  (cost=1629.26..3072.26 rows=100000 width=8) (actual time=5.359..12.639 rows=100000 loops=1)
            ->  Bitmap Index Scan on foo_id_date_idx  (cost=0.00..1604.26 rows=100000 width=0) (actual time=5.299..5.299 rows=100000 loops=1)
```

**QUESTION**
Can `WindowAgg` ever use indexes for sorting? I think that it can't but don't understand why... `GroupAggreagte`s can and it gives good performance improving.

Comment: Your sorting takes place on disk. Try to increase the `work_mem` for your session and see if that improves things

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Yes, I know that improving `work_mem` switches the sorting algorithm to `quick sort` if the memory is enought to do that. But why can't we use sorting provided with the index on `foo(id, date)` along with window functions? With aggregate ones we can.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To match the index you created:

```
CREATE INDEX ON foo(id, date)
```

you would have to make that:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date DESC NULLS LAST)
```

which is the perfect reverse order of `ASC`.

That aside, you could just run:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (id)
       id, date
FROM   foo
ORDER  BY id, date DESC NULLS LAST;
```

But that's probably not what you wanted to ask. Either way, I would make the index:

```
CREATE INDEX ON foo(id, date DESC NULLS LAST)
```

so that `max(date)` is the first index entry per `id`.
Related:

- [PostgreSQL sort by datetime asc, null first?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510509/postgresql-sort-by-datetime-asc-null-first/9511492#9511492)
- [Why do NULL values come first when ordering DESC in a PostgreSQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958679/why-do-null-values-come-first-when-ordering-desc-in-a-postgresql-query/20959470#20959470)
- [Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group/7630564#7630564)
- [Optimize groupwise maximum query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24244026/optimize-groupwise-maximum-query/24377356#24377356)

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work for me. Are you sure about that or maybe I did something wrong...?

Comment: I mean `(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY date ASC NULLS LAST) `

Comment: Awesom, you're just wizard!!! I recreated the index as `CREATE INDEX ON foo(id, date DESC NULLS LAST)` and it works completely fine (performance improved twice). But couldn't you add a little explanation or some references to read more about why creating indexes as I did doesn't work with window aggregates.

Comment: @St.Antario: I added some related answers with a lot more details and links.

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite the logic *"the date is a maximum one among all pairs with the same id"* to a direct translation:

```
SELECT id, date
FROM (
    SELECT id, date, MAX(date) OVER (PARTITION BY id) as maxDate
    FROM foo
) sbt
WHERE date = maxDate;
```

It's not exactly the same as a `ROW_NUMBER`, but a `RANK`, it might return multiple rows with the same `date`