# MySQL SELECT MAX vs ORDER BY LIMIT 1 on WHERE clause

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

SELECT MAX vs ORDER BY LIMIT 1 question has been answered here several times, but if I add a WHERE clause, things change dramatically

Here is my table:

| Field | Type | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| id | b'int' | 'NO' | 'PRI' | None | 'auto_increment' |
| 'open_time' | b'bigint' | 'NO' | 'UNI' | None | '' |

Note, that both columns are indexed.

And here are the requests:

```
SELECT id from table
WHERE open_time > 0
ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1

SELECT MAX(id) from BTCUSDT1mHist
WHERE open_time > 0
```

EXPLAIN ANALYZE shows the following:
ORDER BY:

```
-> Limit: 1 row(s)  (cost=0.10 rows=1) (actual time=0.038..0.038 rows=1 loops=1)
    -> Filter: (table.open_time > 0)  (cost=0.10 rows=1) (actual time=0.037..0.037 rows=1 loops=1)
        -> Index scan on table using PRIMARY (reverse)  (cost=0.10 rows=2) (actual time=0.036..0.036 rows=1 loops=1)
```

MAX():

```
-> Aggregate: max(table.id)  (cost=325890.06 rows=1081033) (actual time=1025.181..1025.181 rows=1 loops=1)
    -> Filter: (table.open_time > 0)  (cost=217786.76 rows=1081033) (actual time=0.032..866.890 rows=2180645 loops=1)
        -> Index range scan on table using open_time  (cost=217786.76 rows=1081033) (actual time=0.031..705.926 rows=2180645 loops=1)
```

ORDER BY finishes in 0.0012 seconds, while MAX() does in 1.026 seconds

I have read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34246403/performance-of-max-vs-order-by-desc-limit-1) also, but it doesn't seem to cover my situation

The question is: why does MAX() takes so much longer than ORDER BY LIMIT?

Comment: The query with MAX will first get all the rows with open_time>0, and then check all `id`s to find the max value for `id`. The query with ORDER BY  will get the last record using the index on id, then check if open_time>0, and return this records, which is much faster if the first found record happens to have an open_time>0.

Comment: @Luuk probably so, but the order of SQL operations should be first WHERE then ORDER BY and LIMIT after that https://www.eversql.com/sql-order-of-operations-sql-query-order-of-execution/

Comment: In general you probably are right, but MySQL *sees* `ORDER BY id LIMIT 1`, and decides that reading on the primary key is most efficient, so it evaluate the `WHERE` in a second step.  In the other query there is no ORDER BY, but where WHERE clause is using open_time, and there is an index on that field, making MySQL choose that index.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compare in the analyze:

```
    -> Index scan on table using PRIMARY (reverse)  (cost=0.10 rows=2) (actual time=0.036..0.036 rows=1 loops=1)
```

Versus:

```
    -> Index range scan on table using open_time  (cost=217786.76 rows=1081033) (actual time=0.031..705.926 rows=2180645 loops=1)
```

Examining 2 rows must be a lot quicker than examining 2,180,645 rows.

In the query with `ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1`, it uses the primary key index. It starts at the end because it's a reverse order. Then it just iterates down the leaf nodes of the index (in descending order), until it examines the first row that also matches `open_time > 0`. Then the [LIMIT optimization](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/limit-optimization.html) allows the query execution to finish. Based on its statistics, it estimates this will happen after examining 2 rows.

In the query with `MAX(id)`, it uses the index on `open_time`. But because it's a range condition `open_time > 0`, it can't assume the maximum id is found at the start or end of that range. So it must examine *every* matching entry in the `open_time` index, searching for the greatest value of `id` (primary keys are implicitly part of a secondary index). There's no chance of early-termination as there is in the query with `LIMIT`.

Comment: thanks for the answer! So, without LIMIT optimization, both MAX and ORDER LIMIT approaches would give more or less similar results?

Comment: I suppose so, but MySQL performs the LIMIT optimization automatically in this query.