# sql query optimization in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization

I am executing the below query in PostgreSQL but it is taking more time than oracle. In PostgreSQL it is taking 1.5 second and in oracle it is taking nearly 0.009 second.

```
select ex1.currency_id,
        ex1.underly_currency_id,
        ex1.type_id,
        ex1.third_id,
        ex1.market_third_id,
        ex1.exch_d,
        ex1.daily_dflt_f,
        ex1.exch_rate,
        ex1.external_seq_no,
        ex1.creation_d,
        ex1.creation_user_id,
        ex1.last_modif_d,
        ex1.last_user_id
        /* security_level_e = 0 */
        FROM aaamaindb.exch_rate ex1
        where ((ex1.currency_id = 1)
         and ( ex1.underly_currency_id = 2)
         and ( ex1.exch_d >= '2003/03/27 00:00:00')
         and ( ex1.exch_d <= '2006/01/15 00:00:00')
         and ( exch_d = (  select max(ex2.exch_d)
            from aaamaindb.exch_rate ex2
            where ex1.currency_id = ex2.currency_id
            and ex1.underly_currency_id = ex2.underly_currency_id
            and ex2.exch_d >= '2003/03/27 00:00:00' and ex2.exch_d <= '2006/01/15 00:00:00'
            and (ex1.type_id = ex2.type_id
                or (ex1.type_id is NULL and ex2.type_id is NULL)) /*PMSTA07173-EFE-081002*/
            and (ex1.third_id = ex2.third_id
                or (ex1.third_id is  NULL and ex2.third_id is NULL))
            and (ex1.market_third_id = ex2.market_third_id
                or (ex1.market_third_id is NULL and ex2.market_third_id is NULL))
            group by type_id, third_id, market_third_id )))
        order by exch_d desc;
```

exch_rate having 45000 record both in postgres and oracle.

Below in the index created on exch_rate table.

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS exch_rate_bk_idx
    ON aaamaindb.exch_rate USING btree
    (currency_id ASC NULLS LAST, exch_d ASC NULLS LAST, underly_currency_id ASC NULLS LAST, type_id ASC NULLS LAST, third_id ASC NULLS LAST, market_third_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;
```

I need to optimize, this sql query to work as fast as oracle.

QUERY PLAN

```
"Sort  (cost=31883.98..31883.99 rows=4 width=97) (actual time=582.557..582.559 rows=1 loops=1)"
"  Sort Key: ex1.exch_d DESC"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on exch_rate ex1  (cost=54.58..31883.94 rows=4 width=97) (actual time=540.145..582.553 rows=1 loops=1)"
"        Recheck Cond: ((currency_id = 1) AND (exch_d >= '2003-03-27 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (exch_d <= '2006-01-15 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (underly_currency_id = 2))"
"        Filter: (exch_d = (SubPlan 1))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 1025"
"        Heap Blocks: exact=21"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on exch_rate_bk_idx  (cost=0.00..54.57 rows=825 width=0) (actual time=0.126..0.127 rows=1026 loops=1)"
"              Index Cond: ((currency_id = 1) AND (exch_d >= '2003-03-27 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (exch_d <= '2006-01-15 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (underly_currency_id = 2))"
"        SubPlan 1"
"          ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=37.66..37.69 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.566..0.566 rows=1 loops=1026)"
"                Group Key: ex2.type_id, ex2.third_id, ex2.market_third_id"
"                ->  Sort  (cost=37.66..37.67 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.411..0.457 rows=1026 loops=1026)"
"                      Sort Key: ex2.type_id, ex2.third_id, ex2.market_third_id"
"                      Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 97kB"
"                      ->  Index Only Scan using exch_rate_bk_idx on exch_rate ex2  (cost=0.41..37.65 rows=1 width=32) (actual time=0.009..0.257 rows=1026 loops=1026)"
"                            Index Cond: ((currency_id = ex1.currency_id) AND (exch_d >= '2003-03-27 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (exch_d <= '2006-01-15 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (underly_currency_id = ex1.underly_currency_id))"
"                            Filter: (((ex1.type_id = type_id) OR ((ex1.type_id IS NULL) AND (type_id IS NULL))) AND ((ex1.third_id = third_id) OR ((ex1.third_id IS NULL) AND (third_id IS NULL))) AND ((ex1.market_third_id = market_third_id) OR ((ex1.market_third_id IS NULL) AND (market_third_id IS NULL))))"
"                            Heap Fetches: 0"
"Planning Time: 0.278 ms"
"Execution Time: 582.691 ms"
```

And DDL for table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS aaamaindb.exch_rate
(
    currency_id bigint NOT NULL,
    underly_currency_id bigint NOT NULL,
    type_id bigint,
    third_id bigint,
    market_third_id bigint,
    exch_d timestamp without time zone NOT NULL,
    daily_dflt_f smallint NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
    exch_rate numeric(23,14) NOT NULL,
    external_seq_no bigint,
    creation_d timestamp without time zone,
    creation_user_id bigint,
    last_modif_d timestamp without time zone,
    last_user_id bigint,
    CONSTRAINT fk_701001 FOREIGN KEY (currency_id)
        REFERENCES aaamaindb.currency (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_701002 FOREIGN KEY (underly_currency_id)
        REFERENCES aaamaindb.currency (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE CASCADE,
    CONSTRAINT fk_701003 FOREIGN KEY (type_id)
        REFERENCES aaamaindb.type (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_701004 FOREIGN KEY (third_id)
        REFERENCES aaamaindb.third_party (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT fk_701005 FOREIGN KEY (market_third_id)
        REFERENCES aaamaindb.third_party (id) MATCH SIMPLE
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION
        ON DELETE RESTRICT,
    CONSTRAINT exch_rate_daily_dflt_chk CHECK (daily_dflt_f = ANY (ARRAY[0, 1]))
)

TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS aaamaindb.exch_rate
    OWNER to v_gen_reg1aaa;

GRANT ALL ON TABLE aaamaindb.exch_rate TO v_gen_reg1aaa;
-- Index: exch_rate_bk_idx

-- DROP INDEX IF EXISTS aaamaindb.exch_rate_bk_idx;

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS exch_rate_bk_idx
    ON aaamaindb.exch_rate USING btree
    (currency_id ASC NULLS LAST, exch_d ASC NULLS LAST, underly_currency_id ASC NULLS LAST, type_id ASC NULLS LAST, third_id ASC NULLS LAST, market_third_id ASC NULLS LAST)
    TABLESPACE pg_default;

-- Trigger: d_after_exch_rate_trg

-- DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS d_after_exch_rate_trg ON aaamaindb.exch_rate;

CREATE TRIGGER d_after_exch_rate_trg
    AFTER DELETE
    ON aaamaindb.exch_rate
    FOR EACH STATEMENT
    EXECUTE FUNCTION aaamaindb.d_after_exch_rate_trg();

-- Trigger: i_after_exch_rate_trg

-- DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS i_after_exch_rate_trg ON aaamaindb.exch_rate;

CREATE TRIGGER i_after_exch_rate_trg
    AFTER INSERT
    ON aaamaindb.exch_rate
    FOR EACH STATEMENT
    EXECUTE FUNCTION aaamaindb.i_after_exch_rate_trg();

-- Trigger: i_before_row_exch_rate_trg

-- DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS i_before_row_exch_rate_trg ON aaamaindb.exch_rate;

CREATE TRIGGER i_before_row_exch_rate_trg
    BEFORE INSERT
    ON aaamaindb.exch_rate
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION aaamaindb.i_before_row_exch_rate_trg();

-- Trigger: u_after_exch_rate_trg

-- DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS u_after_exch_rate_trg ON aaamaindb.exch_rate;

CREATE TRIGGER u_after_exch_rate_trg
    AFTER UPDATE 
    ON aaamaindb.exch_rate
    FOR EACH STATEMENT
    EXECUTE FUNCTION aaamaindb.u_after_exch_rate_trg();

-- Trigger: u_before_row_exch_rate_trg

-- DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS u_before_row_exch_rate_trg ON aaamaindb.exch_rate;

CREATE TRIGGER u_before_row_exch_rate_trg
    BEFORE UPDATE 
    ON aaamaindb.exch_rate
    FOR EACH ROW
    EXECUTE FUNCTION aaamaindb.u_before_row_exch_rate_trg();


Below is Oracle Explain plan

 OPERATION   OBJECT_NAME     OPTIONS     CARDINALITY     COST 

 SELECT STATEMENT 
         1   92 
        
 TABLE ACCESS 
 AAAMAINDB.EXCH_RATE     BY INDEX ROWID      1   8 
                
 INDEX 
 AAAMAINDB.EXCH_RATE_BK_IDX      RANGE SCAN DESCENDING   1   7 
                        
 Access Predicates 
                                
 AND 
                                        
 EX1.CURRENCY_ID=1 
                                        
 EX1.EXCH_D>=TIMESTAMP' 2003-03-27 00:00:00' 
                                        
 EX1.UNDERLY_CURRENCY_ID=2 
                                        
 EX1.EXCH_D<=TIMESTAMP' 2006-01-15 00:00:00' 
                        
 Filter Predicates 
                                
 AND 
                                        
 EX1.UNDERLY_CURRENCY_ID=2 
                                        
 EXCH_D= (SELECT MAX(EX2.EXCH_D) FROM AAAMAINDB.EXCH_RATE EX2 WHERE EX2.EXCH_D<=TIMESTAMP' 2006-01-15 00:00:00' AND EX2.EXCH_D>=TIMESTAMP' 2003-03-27 00:00:00' AND EX2.CURRENCY_ID=:B1 AND EX2.UNDERLY_CURRENCY_ID=:B2 AND (:B3 IS NULL AND EX2.MARKET_THIRD_ID IS NULL OR EX2.MARKET_THIRD_ID=:B4) AND (EX2.TYPE_ID=:B5 OR EX2.TYPE_ID IS NULL AND :B6 IS NULL) AND (EX2.THIRD_ID=:B7 OR :B8 IS NULL AND EX2.THIRD_ID IS NULL) GROUP BY TYPE_ID,THIRD_ID,MARKET_THIRD_ID) 
                        
 HASH 
     GROUP BY    1   4 
                                
 INDEX 
 AAAMAINDB.EXCH_RATE_BK_IDX      RANGE SCAN      1   3 
                                        
 Access Predicates 
                                                
 AND 
                                                        
 EX2.CURRENCY_ID=:B1 
                                                        
 EX2.EXCH_D>=TIMESTAMP' 2003-03-27 00:00:00' 
                                                        
 EX2.UNDERLY_CURRENCY_ID=:B2 
                                                        
 EX2.EXCH_D<=TIMESTAMP' 2006-01-15 00:00:00' 
                                        
 Filter Predicates 
                                                
 AND 
                                                        
 EX2.UNDERLY_CURRENCY_ID=:B1 
                                                        
 OR 
                                                                
 AND 
                                                                        
 :B2 IS NULL 
                                                                        
 EX2.MARKET_THIRD_ID IS NULL 
                                                                
 EX2.MARKET_THIRD_ID=:B3 
                                                        
 OR 
                                                                
 EX2.TYPE_ID=:B4 
                                                                
 AND 
                                                                        
 EX2.TYPE_ID IS NULL 
                                                                        
 :B5 IS NULL 
                                                        
 OR 
                                                                
 EX2.THIRD_ID=:B6 
                                                                
 AND 
                                                                        
 :B7 IS NULL 
                                                                        
 EX2.THIRD_ID IS NULL 
        
 Other XML 
                
 {info} 
                        
 info type="db_version" 
                                
 12.2.0.1 
                        
 info type="parse_schema" 
                        
 "SYS" 
                        
 info type="plan_hash_full" 
                                
 3996335147 
                        
 info type="plan_hash" 
                                
 3334517769 
                        
 info type="plan_hash_2" 
                                
 3996335147 
                        
 {hint} 
                                
 USE_HASH_AGGREGATION(@"SEL$2") 
                                
 INDEX(@"SEL$2" "EX2"@"SEL$2" ("EXCH_RATE"."CURRENCY_ID" "EXCH_RATE"."EXCH_D" "EXCH_RATE"."UNDERLY_CURRENCY_ID" "EXCH_RATE"."TYPE_ID" "EXCH_RATE"."THIRD_ID" "EXCH_RATE"."MARKET_THIRD_ID")) 
                                
 PUSH_SUBQ(@"SEL$2") 
                                
 INDEX_RS_DESC(@"SEL$1" "EX1"@"SEL$1" ("EXCH_RATE"."CURRENCY_ID" "EXCH_RATE"."EXCH_D" "EXCH_RATE"."UNDERLY_CURRENCY_ID" "EXCH_RATE"."TYPE_ID" "EXCH_RATE"."THIRD_ID" "EXCH_RATE"."MARKET_THIRD_ID")) 
                                
 OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$1") 
                                
 OUTLINE_LEAF(@"SEL$2") 
                                
 ALL_ROWS 
                                
 DB_VERSION('12.2.0.1') 
                                
 OPTIMIZER_FEATURES_ENABLE('12.2.0.1') 
                                
 IGNORE_OPTIM_EMBEDDED_HINTS
```

Comment: A difference that big would suggest you got the Oracle result from some sort of client, pool or [server cache](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/tgdba/tuning-result-cache.html), which isn't really apples to apples comparison unless you set up a similar thing for PostgreSQL, or measure the time it takes Oracle to actually run the query.

Comment: Could you please share the results from `explain(analyze, verbose, buffers)` of this statement and the DDL for all tables and indexes involved? As an update to your question, in plain text.

Comment: And if possible can you share Oracle' s execution plan too?

Comment: I don't know what the best way to share an Oracle query plan is (I haven't worked with them very much in a long time), but with your current formatting it is unreadable.

Comment: Pls check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/4808122) how to post the Oracle explain plan

Answer (score 0):

Your subquery seems pretty fragile.  You will get an error if your subquery returns more than one row.  And if it can't return more than one row, than your GROUP BY is useless.

The use of a both a range condition and an equality condition on ex1.exch_d seems rather suspect.

The first two columns in your index should be the ones tested for simple equality, currency_id and underly_currency_id.  Having exch_d come before underly_currency_id will ruin must of the latter's indexable selectivity (in the subquery).

That Oracle is faster here doesn't tell us anything without knowing the plan used by Oracle, or at least what indexes you have in Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

put it here since it won't fit in the comments :

1. execution plan shows bad estimation, maybe look into your table statistics and update them ! (look into `analyze`)
2. an index for the columns you are grouping by in the subquery would be helpful (use the same order in your group by as in your index)
3. you can optimize your query to avoid the subquery by using window function like so :

```
with cte as (
    select
    ex1.currency_id,
    ex1.underly_currency_id,
    ex1.type_id,
    ex1.third_id,
    ex1.market_third_id,
    ex1.exch_d,
    ex1.daily_dflt_f,
    ex1.exch_rate,
    ex1.external_seq_no,
    ex1.creation_d,
    ex1.creation_user_id,
    ex1.last_modif_d,
    ex1.last_user_id, 
    row_number() over (partition by type_id, third_id, market_third_id order by exch_d desc) rn
FROM  aaamaindb.exch_rate ex1
where   ex1.currency_id = 1
        and ex1.underly_currency_id = 2
        and ex1.exch_d >= '2003/03/27 00:00:00'
        and ex1.exch_d <= '2006/01/15 00:00:00'
) 
select * from cte
where rn = 1
order by exch_d desc
```

you still want to adjust the partition by in this query if you ended up using this query

Answer (score 0):

Your PostgreSQL query has one obvious problem.
First a
`Bitmap Index Scan on exch_rate_bk_idx`
is performed with

`Index Cond: ((currency_id = 1) AND (exch_d >= '2003-03-27 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (exch_d <= '2006-01-15 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (underly_currency_id = 2))"`

Which produces actual 1026 rows. All those rows are filtered with `SubPlan 1` except for one with the highest `exch_d`. *Each call* of `SubPlan 1` scan again all the 1026 rows…

This query **does not scale** for a high number of "version" rows with different `exch_d`

Oracle can produce a different execution plan as shown below (on a bit simplified query)

```
select  
* from tab t 
where t.currency_id = 1 and t.underly_currency_id = 2
and t.exch_d = 
 (select max(exch_d) from tab t2
  where t.currency_id = t2.currency_id and 
  t.underly_currency_id = t2.underly_currency_id)


------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                           | Name    | Starts | E-Rows | A-Rows |   A-Time   | Buffers | Reads  |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                    |         |      1 |        |      1 |00:00:00.09 |     355 |    350 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID BATCHED| TAB     |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.09 |     355 |    350 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN                  | TAB_IDX |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.09 |     354 |    349 |
|   3 |    SORT AGGREGATE                   |         |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |      0 |
|   4 |     FIRST ROW                       |         |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |      0 |
|*  5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN (MIN/MAX)     | TAB_IDX |      1 |      1 |      1 |00:00:00.01 |       3 |      0 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 
Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------
 
   2 - access("T"."CURRENCY_ID"=1 AND "T"."UNDERLY_CURRENCY_ID"=2)
       filter("T"."EXCH_D"=)
   5 - access("T2"."CURRENCY_ID"=:B1 AND "T2"."UNDERLY_CURRENCY_ID"=:B2)
```

The key is the operation `INDEX RANGE SCAN (MIN/MAX)` that access the index to get the `max` value of  `exch_d` (line 5). This value is used as a filter in the second access (line2).
So basically, you access the index only twice, not `1 + N` times as in PostgreSQL.

The first thing to do is to remove the **superfluous** `GROUP BY` in you subquery. A well-designed correlated subquery must produce only one row, so grouping is not required.

Second, order your index so that the *versioning attribute* (`exch_d`) is on the last place and define it with  [`DESC NULLS LAST`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34259643/4808122)

Basically you want to see in the execution plan for the subquery

```
   ->  Index Only Scan using index ...
```

preceeded with

```
  ->  Limit ... rows = 1 ...
```

You will stay on the `1 + N` index access (`N` is the number of the rows with different `exch_d`) but the `N` will be done very effective due to `limit 1`

I do not know if in PostgreSQL is possible an execution plan similar to Oracles `INDEX RANGE SCAN (MIN/MAX)`