# Generate_series in Postgres from start and end date in a table

Tags: sql, postgresql, aggregate-functions, generate-series

I have been trying to generate a series of dates (YYYY-MM-DD HH) from the first until the last date in a timestamp field. I've got the `generate_series()` I need, however running into an issue when trying to grab the start and end dates from a table. I have the following to give a rough idea:

```
with date1 as
(
SELECT start_timestamp as first_date
FROM header_table
ORDER BY start_timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1
),
date2 as
(
SELECT start_timestamp as first_date
FROM header_table
ORDER BY start_timestamp ASC    
LIMIT 1
)
    select generate_series(date1.first_date, date2.first_date
                         , '1 hour'::interval)::timestamp as date_hour

from
(   select * from date1
    union
    select * from date2) as foo
```

**Postgres 9.3**

Comment: As *always*, your version of Postgres please. What exactly is the "issue" you mention?

Comment: Postgres v9.3 - my apologies!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You don't need a CTE for this, that would be more expensive than necessary.
And you don't need to cast to `timestamp`, the result already *is* of data type `timestamp` when you feed `timestamp` types to [`generate_series()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html). Details here:

- [Generating time series between two dates in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14113469/generating-time-series-between-two-dates-in-postgresql/46499873#46499873)

In Postgres **9.3** or later you can use a `LATERAL` join:

```
SELECT to_char(ts, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24') AS formatted_ts
FROM  (
   SELECT min(start_timestamp) as first_date
        , max(start_timestamp) as last_date
   FROM   header_table
   ) h
  , generate_series(h.first_date, h.last_date, interval '1 hour') g(ts);
```

Optionally with [`to_char()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html) to get the result as text in the format you mentioned.

This works in ***any*** Postgres version:

```
SELECT generate_series(min(start_timestamp)
                     , max(start_timestamp)
                     , interval '1 hour') AS ts
FROM   header_table;
```

Typically a bit faster.
Calling set-returning functions in the `SELECT` list is a non-standard-SQL feature and frowned upon by some. Also, there were behavioral oddities (though not for this simple case) that were eventually fixed in Postgres 10. See:

- [What is the expected behaviour for multiple set-returning functions in SELECT clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39863505/what-is-the-expected-behaviour-for-multiple-set-returning-functions-in-select-cl/39864815#39864815)

**Note** a subtle difference in **NULL** handling:

The equivalent of

```
max(start_timestamp)
```

is obtained with

```
ORDER BY start_timestamp DESC NULLS LAST
LIMIT 1
```

Without `NULLS LAST` NULL values come *first* in descending order (if there *can* be NULL values in `start_timestamp`). You would get NULL for `last_date` and your query would come up empty.

Details:

- [Why do NULL values come first when ordering DESC in a PostgreSQL query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20958679/why-do-null-values-come-first-when-ordering-desc-in-a-postgresql-query/20959470#20959470)

Comment: Thanks for the thorough help, definitely appreciate it.

Comment: I accepted this as the right answer after evaluating Gordon Linoff and Used_By_Already. Their answers where great, and work nicely. However this shaved about 20-30ms off the time. In a huge system running almost 24x7 on hundreds of tables, this will make a difference (albeit however small).

Comment: In the first code example what is the `g(ts);` referring to?

Comment: @RyderBrooks: `g(ts)` are table and column alias (omitting the optional keyword `AS`) . See: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-TABLE-ALIASES

Answer (score 6):

How about using aggregation functions instead?

```
with dates as (
      SELECT min(start_timestamp) as first_date, max(start_timestamp) as last_date
      FROM header_table
     )
select generate_series(first_date, last_date, '1 hour'::interval)::timestamp as date_hour
from dates;
```

Or even:

```
select generate_series(min(start_timestamp),
                       max(start_timestamp),
                       '1 hour'::interval
                      )::timestamp as date_hour
from header_table;
```

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
with dateRange as
  (
  SELECT min(start_timestamp) as first_date, max(start_timestamp) as last_date
  FROM header_table
  )
select 
    generate_series(first_date, last_date, '1 hour'::interval)::timestamp as date_hour
from dateRange
```

**NB:** You want the 2 dates in **a** row, not on separate rows.

<kbd>[see this sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/e0535/1)</kbd>