# Understanding some MySQL Optimization tips

Tags: mysql, optimization, max

Hey, I was looking up some ways to make my MySQL queries more optimized, I bought some into practice but for some I wish to understand why they are recommended.

For example not using "LIMIT 10000,10" as I learned that MySQL reads 10010 rows, throws away the 10000 and returns the 10.

Now what I want to know is:

Referring to this article: http://forge.mysql.com/wiki/Top10SQLPerformanceTips

"Use a clever key and ORDER BY instead of MAX"

1. What is a "clever key" ?
2. What execution path does MySQL take to calculate MAX that it has been recommended to avoid it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A clever key is a key that will allow the mysql to read the rows according to the wanted order, thus not using filesort or temporary tables for the sorting.

It does **not** have to be a primary key. To learn when you can use such a key for sorting read this very useful article: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: Galz, your definition makes sense, but, just out of curiosity, how did you figure it out?  If I search mySql and "Clever Key", there are 462 results; all of them a derivative of the linked list in this article.  Additionally, if I do the same search and exclude all links that have the text "Use a clever key and ORDER BY instead of MAX", I get 6 non-related results.  Granted, Google is not all powerful with its terms (yet), but just curious how the "clever key" term got coined.

Comment: @ray023 - clever key is not a coined term. Akay could have asked about an efficient key or a good key just the same:) I found the article above a shirt while ago and it came to my mind when reading this question - search google for "mysql order by optimization", that article would be the first result.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to take a stab at question 1 and say a "clever key" is a primary key on a table which has value when ordered a certain way.  (e.g. A hotel database with a table that tracks when guests check in.  Make the primary key of the table the TimeStamp of the check-in.  Then, when you need to know the most recent check-ins, you can order by the primary key in descending order).  I suppose that is faster than having a table that uses an auto-incrementing integer as the primary key and a Timestamp field.

You might find your answer to Question 2 in [this stackoverflow discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426731/min-max-vs-order-by-and-limit).  It should give you an idea of the execution path, but doesn't necessarily compare it the *clever key* mentioned in your link.