# How can I get the last row value with MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I have a table called `Live`, and in the table I have `public_id`. In `public_id` are numbers (e.g. 1,2,3,4,5). How can I get the highest number or the last entry's number?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd choose

```
SELECT public_id FROM Live ORDER BY public_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

It has already been posted, but i'll add something more:

If you perform this query usually you can create an index with inverted ordering.

Something like:

```
CREATE INDEX ON Live (public_id DESC)
```

Please Note

> DESC

PHP + MySQL code:

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query('SELECT public_id FROM Live ORDER BY public_id DESC LIMIT 1;');
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {
   $max_public_id = mysql_fetch_row($result);
   echo $max_public_id[0]; //Here it is
}
?>
```

Comment: All this prints out is `array`, how can I get the individual number like 4?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. I edited it. BTW. You should try to get in the insights of the language. You can print array content with print_r() function. Take a look at php.net

Comment: I did know about `print_r();` but didn't think that would resolve the problem. This worked, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT public_id FROM Live ORDER BY public_id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

would give you the highest number

Edit:  For the php

```
$conn = mysql_connect(....
$query = "SELECT public_id FROM Live ORDER BY public_id DESC LIMIT 1";
$result = mysql_query($query, $conn);
```

Comment: This won't print anything out. When I try this. How do I echo it out?

Comment: @Pete print $result; and also print "$result"; work, but I don't know which one is correct.  My php is limited.

Answer (score 3):

Another option is to use `MAX`, ie

```
SELECT MAX(public_id) FROM Live
```

Comment: It's still a valid answer to the question. Is it really slower depends on data...

Comment: I didn't downvote, I just added the information as the performance issue can be very important.

Comment: @FrankS: In the link you provided, the answer states that `MIN()` is actually (sliightly) **faster** than `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1`.

Comment: This answer is 100% correct. It will use the index (if there is one!) of `public_id`. The other way (`ORDER BY ... LIMIT`) has the advantage that it can return the whole row with maximum id - with `SELECT *` - and also more than one rows - with `LIMIT x` .

Comment: My fault, so I deleted the old comment. Here is the [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426731/min-max-vs-order-by-and-limit) to the answer I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `ORDER BY public_id DESC LIMIT 1;` to obtain the record with the highest id (I guess you are using autoincrement attribute on public_id) or `MySQL MAX()` function like this:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE public_id = MAX(public_id);
```

edit:

Here is how you will do it in php:

```
// executing the QUERY request to MySQL server, mysql_query() returns resource ID
$result = mysql_query('SELECT public_id FROM Live ORDER BY public_id DESC LIMIT 1');
// then we use this resource ID to fetch the actual value MySQL have returned
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_FETCH_ASSOC);
// $row variable now holds all the data we got from MySQL, its an array, so we just output the public_id column value to the screen
echo $row['public_id']; // you can use var_dump($row); to see the whole content of $row
```

Comment: So how would you get the number? Sorry this may sound like a stupid question but I'm still new to MySQL. Would you say $last_number = SELECT public_id FROM Live ORDER BY public_id DESC LIMIT 1;?

Comment: As the query tells MySQL to return only one record and this is the record having the highest public_id number it will contain that value (the highest number).