# MYSQL - Get unique minimum value

Tags: mysql

In a table that has the columns: `'product_id', 'price',` ... (and others). I need to obtain the record with the lowest and unique price for a given product_id.
I tried different sentences without having the expected result. Finally I came across this sentence (for `product_id = 2`):

```
SELECT `price` , `product_id`
FROM bids
WHERE `product_id` = 2
GROUP BY `price`
HAVING COUNT( `price` ) = 1
ORDER BY `price`
LIMIT 1;
```

But it seems not to be an elegant solution having recourse to `LIMIT` and `ORDER`. How can I obtain the same record using the `MIN()` function or even something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work because you are already specifying the `product_id` to analyze:

```sql
SELECT MIN(t1.price) AS price, t1.product_id
FROM
(
    SELECT price, product_id
    FROM bids
    WHERE product_id = 1
    GROUP BY price, product_id
    HAVING COUNT(price) = 1
) t1
```

Notes: [MIN/MAX vs ORDER BY and LIMIT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426731/min-max-vs-order-by-and-limit)

Comment: This works! Do you think that using this sentence rather than mine would improve the efficiency of the MySQL call? 
Even if not, it seems to be a neater solution.

Comment: @Enric, I'd like to refer you to an old post! See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426731/min-max-vs-order-by-and-limit I've also modified my answer to include it..

Comment: Thank you very much. Your answer was helpful, up to now is what I'm going to use.

Answer (score 0):

Skydreamer, I'm not sure but as I understand it the op wants the the first unique value.
If the prices are 1,1,2,2,3 the query should return the row with the price of 3.

Comment: So I had badly understood the question. Removed the answer !