# Order by Primary Key and Index

Tags: mysql, indexing

For many SQL queries, the "order by id desc" is a required component to get the latest rows. The general query will be something like

```
select * from table X where some_condition order by id desc
```

In general, does the "order by id" slow down the query very much?

Specifically, for query like:

```
select * from table X where some_col = some_value order by id desc
```

Do we really need to add index (some_col, id) to speed up the query?

In all cases, it is assumed that ID is auto incremental.

---

My confusion comes from the following guideline about order-by optimization:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html

Comment: Since you are asking about performance [this SO discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426731/min-max-vs-order-by-and-limit) will give you a better understanding on using min/max, index and talks about limit as well.

Comment: Your link is very helpful, but it talked specifically about aggregated query vs order-by, and not so much related to my question.

Comment: You asked about speeding up using an index and mentioned order by. If you read the accepted answer it can give you a lot actually and can help you think how you can implement a solution. Don't want to duplicate here what has been explained there already.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table X where some_col = some_value order by id desc
```

In queries like this,  you need an index on some_col for sure. According to me index on (some_col) should be good enough over (some_col, id).

[MySQL merge index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/index-merge-optimization.html) should help you to use the index on id for sorting.

Also (id,some_Col) index will never be used when you search on some_col, while (some_col, id) will be.

Comment: I used to create index on some_col (as you said "for sure"). But after reading the article: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html, I guess that a single index on some_col is not good enough. But it's still confusing because the key in "order by" is primary key.

Comment: Can you pls mention which one is confusing you. The below query is said to use the index. 
SELECT * FROM t1
  WHERE key_part1=1
  ORDER BY key_part1 DESC, key_part2 DESC;

Comment: I confuse because in order to achieve the best performance (for queries as I posted), the key should be (key_part1, key_part2) -- or (some_col, id). But a multiple index like that is pretty weird.

Comment: I believe the concept of merge index optimizations shld come to play here. Though I am not sure abt it.

Answer (score 2):

Index on (some_col) is enough because MySql add the primary key as part of the index in innodb tables. So implicitly you will have (some_col, id) as index.
You can check this article for more info :
[Can MySQL use primary key values from a secondary index?](http://www.psce.com/blog/2012/05/17/can-mysql-use-primary-key-values-from-a-secondary-index/)

Answer (score 0):

To get the first row you could also use this:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableX
WHERE id = (SELECT MIN(id)
            FROM tableX
            WHERE some conditions)
```

and this for the last:

```
SELECT *
FROM tableX
WHERE id = (SELECT MAX(id)
            FROM tableX
            WHERE some conditions)
```

but of course yes, an index on `id` and an index on `some_col` will be very useful to speed up the query.