# SELECT rows with the second highest value in a column

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

Let's say I have a table similar to the following:

```
Item         Description            Time
-----        -----------            -----
ItemA1       descript               08-16-2013 00:00:00
ItemA2       descript               08-16-2013 00:00:00
ItemA3       descript               08-16-2013 00:00:00
.
.
ItemAN       descript               08-16-2013 00:00:00

ItemB1       descript               08-13-2013 00:00:00
ItemB2       descript               08-13-2013 00:00:00
ItemB3       descript               08-13-2013 00:00:00
.
.
ItemBN       descript               08-13-2013 00:00:00
.
.
.
ItemX1       descript               01-13-2012 00:00:00
ItemX2       descript               01-13-2012 00:00:00
ItemX3       descript               01-13-2012 00:00:00
.
.
ItemXN       descript               01-13-2012 00:00:00
```

Groups of items are added periodically. When a group of items is added they are all added with the same "Time" field. "Time" essentially serves as a unique index for that item group.

I want to SELECT the group of items that have the second highest time. In this example my query should pull the "B" items. I know I can do max(`time`) to SELECT the "A" items, but I don't know how I would do second last.

My "Time" columns are stored as TIMESTAMP if that means anything.

Comment: You should probably test both MAX and LIMIT/ORDER BY solutions, as there can be performance downside to LIMITs, depending on availability of indexes.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426731/min-max-vs-order-by-and-limit

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can try something like:

```
SELECT MAX(Time)
FROM yourTable
WHERE Time < (SELECT MAX(Time) FROM yourTable)
```

[**<kbd>SQLFiddle Demo</kbd>**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7b29/1)

Comment: +1 for nice sql fiddle button, but your query gives not items, but just time

Comment: @DarkAjax, This solution doesn't scale at all. How would you select the 3rd highest then? Or 4th, 5th, 6th, nth?

Comment: This will only find the second largest value, not the ROW with the second highest value

Answer (score 7):

One approach:

```
SELECT t.*
 FROM mytable t
 JOIN ( SELECT l.time
          FROM mytable l
         GROUP BY l.time
         ORDER BY l.time DESC
         LIMIT 1,1 
      ) m
   ON m.time = t.time
```

This uses an inline view (assigned an alias of m) to return the second "greatest" time value. The GROUP BY gets us a distinct list, the ORDER BY DESC puts the latest first, and the "trick" is the LIMIT, which returns the second row.  LIMIT(m,n)  = (skip first m rows, return next n rows)

With that time value, we can join back to the original table, to get all rows that have a matching time value.

---

Performance will be enhanced with an index with leading column of `time`. (I think MySQL should be able to avoid a "Using filesort" operation, and get the result from the inline view query fairly quickly.)

But, including a predicate in the inline view query, if you "know" that the second latest time will never be more than a certain number of days old, won't hurt performance:

```
   WHERE l.time > NOW() + INTERVAL -30 DAYS
```

But with that added, then the query won't return the "second latest" group if it's `time` is more than 30 days ago.

The `SELECT MAX(time) WHERE time < ( SELECT MAX(time)` approach to get the second latest (the approach given in other answers) might be faster, especially if there is no index with leading column of `time`, but performance would best be gauged by actual testing. The index with leading column of time will speed up the MAX() approach as well.)

The query I provided can be easily extended to get the 4th latest, 42nd latest, etc, by changing the `LIMIT` clause... `LIMIT(3,1)`, `LIMIT(41,1)`, etc.

Comment: *NOTE:* the query in this answer uses MySQL specific `LIMIT` syntax, which is *not* supported in most (every) other commercial databases.

Comment: LIMIT syntax in a subquery is not supported for earlier versions of MySQL.

Comment: @Manu: And older versions of MySQL don't even support inline views or subqueries at all.

Answer (score 6):

This should give you second biggest time:

```
SELECT time FROM table GROUP BY time ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1,1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  T1.ITEM
FROM    YOURTABLE T1
WHERE   T1.TIME = ( SELECT  MAX(T2.TIME) 
                    FROM    YOURTABLE T2 
                    WHERE   T2.TIME < ( SELECT  MAX(T3.TIME) 
                                        FROM    YOURTABLE T3
                                    )
                )
```

Answer (score 1):

Get second, third, fourth......Nth highest value using following query:

```
SELECT MIN(value) from yourTable WHERE value IN( SELECT TOP N value FROM yourTable ORDER BY value DESC)
```

Replace N by you number i.e. N=2 for second highest value, N=3 for third highest value and so on. So for second highest value use:

```
SELECT MIN(value) from yourTable WHERE value IN( SELECT TOP 2 value FROM yourTable ORDER BY value DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something really straightforward like this should work

```
select * from my-table where time = 
  (Select top 1 time
     from (select top 2 time from my-table order by time desc)
   order by time asc)
```

Comment: `TOP` is Microsoft SQL Server syntax, not supported by MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another solution which I think should work for your problem:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE xHighest AS (SELECT DISTINCT Time FROM `my-table` ORDER BY Time DESC LIMIT 1,1);

SELECT * FROM `my-table` JOIN xHighest ON (my-table.Time = xHighest.Time);
```

You can choose if **second, third, ... highest value** should be used by changing the first parameter of LIMIT.

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL: limit base solution

> Example: records 1, 2, 3, 4, 5.
>
> LIMIT 2,1 means it will return 3rd highest number, as LIMIT 1,1 return 2nd highest number and so on

SELECT rc.`rc_officer_id` FROM recovery_complain_officer rc ORDER BY rc.`rc_officer_id` DESC LIMIT 2,1

Answer (score 0):

Leftfield-ish answer, but this allows you to select n-1 ordered values from a single table as you want (credit to the https://stackoverflow.com/a/35234692/618320 answer by @Uueerdo), with *nearly* no extra cost.

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT...)`, followed by some `SUBSTRING(...)`,

```
SELECT
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(groupTime, ',', 1) AS time1,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(groupTime, ',', 2), ',', -1) AS time2,
  SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(groupTime, ',', 3), ',', -1) AS time3
FROM (
  SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT Time ORDER BY Time DESC) groupTime FROM mytable) t
```

The inner query would give you a single-row result back like "08-16-2013 00:00:00,08-13-2013 00:00:00,01-13-2012 00:00:00", and splitting that string up the way we are doing, gives you a table result like,

```
time1                 time2                time3
---------             ------------         ------------
08-16-2013 00:00:00   08-13-2013 00:00:00  01-13-2012 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe TOP and START AT can help here.
I have used this in Sybase SQL.

SELECT TOP 1 START AT 2 * FROM Table_Name ORDER BY CREATEDDATETIME DESC;