# How to get the first ID with SQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I am trying to get the first id with a specific date.
So this is my code:

```
$checkm = "SELECT FIRST(id) FROM times WHERE date='2014-03-07'";
$resultm = mysqli_query($con,$checkm);
```

I have a table called `times` and there are some columns. Two of them are `date` and `id`.

I am trying to get the first row's id with the date `2014-03-07`.

**EDIT:** Fixed!

```
$checkm = "SELECT id FROM times WHERE date='2014-03-06' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1";
$resultm = mysqli_query($con,$checkm); 

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultm)) {
    $resultm1 = $row['id'];
}
```

Comment: Use LIMIT in query `SELECT id FROM times WHERE date='2014-03-07' LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pretty straightforward...

```
SELECT id FROM times WHERE date='2014-03-07' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Thank you its working! script: $checkm="SELECT id FROM times WHERE date='2014-03-06' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1"; $resultm=mysqli_query($con,$checkm); while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resultm)) { $resultm1=$row['id']; }

Comment: This Stack Overflow posting discusses the potentially significant differences in performance of using LIMIT vs MIN (or MAX). So be careful if you have chosen this route. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/426731/min-max-vs-order-by-and-limit

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the minimum id.

```
SELECT min(id) 
FROM times 
WHERE date = '2014-03-07'
```

Comment: so you quote my answer and vote another :P not that he's wrong, in fact his solution is more elegant for the given problem, but mine's more flexible incase you want to change how you would define "first"