# SQL to return the latest record

Tags: mysql, sql

One of the columns in my table has data type as TIMESTAMP. I would like get the latest record from the table using the timestamp column. The records in the table could vary between a few hundreds to millions. The query looks like this currently.

```
SELECT alarm_severity_id
FROM alarm_notification
WHERE alarm_life_cycle_id = 25
ORDER BY event_timestamp DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Because of the number of records in the table, I suspect the query can take quite a bit of time (depending on the records). Of course I can put an index on the event_timestamp column to improve on performance. However, I am curious to know if this is the best query to get the results. Or is there any other PROPER way of doing it.

Comment: You are going in the right direction. I think this is the best way to do it. Create a index and get max timestamp.

Comment: @Egalitarian Thnx. But I was expecting something like a MAX funtion to do the trick for me. Sorting the data and then limiting the results to 1 seems like a workaround to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to find out the *maximum timestamp* and then the corresponding `alarm_severity_id`:

```
select alarm_severity_id
  from alarm_notification
 where (alarm_life_cycle_id = 25) and
       (event_timestamp in 
          (select Max(event_timestamp)
             from alarm_notification
            where alarm_life_cycle_id = 25))
 limit 1
```

Create an *index* on `event_timestamp` field (if you don't have one)

Comment: If this is quicker I'll eat a small part of my shoe.

Answer (score 2):

The way to go is to create one INDEX of two columns, first being the alarm_life_cycle_id and second the event_timestamp.

```
ALTER TABLE `alarm_notification` ADD INDEX `my_index` (`alarm_life_cycle_id`, `event_timestamp`)
```

With this index in place, the difference between `MIN()` `MAX()` and `ORDER BY ... LIMIT 1` will be practically negligible please see more : https://stackoverflow.com/a/426785/953684