# SQLAlchemy: Return a record filtered by max value of a column

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

All, I'm having an issue with a SQLA request; **the goal** is to return a record with the maximum value in the counter column:

this works fine - returns proper record:

```
m=12 # arbitrary example of a max value of counter = 12
qry = session.query(Data).
      filter(Data.user_id == user_id,Data.counter == m)
```

The code below does not work- returns `None`:

```
from sqlalchemy import func
qry = session.query(Data).
      filter(Data.user_id == user_id,
      Data.counter == func.max(Data.counter).select())
```

Note that there's never more than one record with a maximum value (if that's relevant).

Surely there's a way to return a record having the max value in one of the columns. Any Ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It sounds like you could simply sort by counter in descending order and take the first result...

```
from sqlalchemy import desc

qry = session.query(Data).filter(
      Data.user_id == user_id).order_by(
      desc(Data.counter).limit(1)
```

However if you're concerned about sorting a large dataset, you could use a subquery...

```
subqry = session.query(func.max(Data.counter)).filter(Data.user_id == user_id)
qry = session.query(Data).filter(Data.user_id == user_id, Data.counter == subqry)
```

The sql that `qry` would essentially be...

```
SELECT * 
FROM data 
WHERE data.user_id = :user_id AND data.counter = (
    SELECT max(data.counter) AS max_1 
    FROM data 
    WHERE data.user_id = :user_id GROUP BY data.user_id
);
```

Comment: this is not very resource-efficient, instead finding a max and retrieving a single record, we will wind up sorting an entire (potentially very long) list. Looking for something more efficient.

Comment: Edited to show an alternative method using a subquery.

Comment: It can also be done with a [left outer join](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745609/sql-select-only-rows-with-max-value-on-a-column) but I'm not sure off hand how that would be expressed cleanly with sqlalchemy

Comment: Is the subquery likely to be any more efficient? It seems to me that it would add processing - the data was already sorted by the counter column to get the maximum, and then it has to scan the table to find matching items.

Comment: Using `max` shouldn't be as expensive as sorting. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426731/min-max-vs-order-by-and-limit

Comment: you can index the field if it is a speed problem with a large table.

Comment: @GG_Python that is incorrect.  The whole query is passed to the RDBMS.  Most RDBMS will take account of the `limit` when planning their query.  If the table is indexed it will not cause the data to be sorted.  If the table is not indexed then the RDBMS must read the whole table from disk whatever query you pass it.