# How to retrieve data from the latest date in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

In mySql, I can perform to data of latest date as follows:

```
select * from tbl where date = 'select max(date) from tbl';
```

But I don't know how to do this is laravel? How to do it?

Comment: Alternatively, you can execute SQL as strings in Laravel with "DB::select(...)"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

use `orderbBy()`:

```
TblModel::orderBy('date','DESC')->first();
```

Or

```
DB::table('tbl')->orderBy('date', 'DESC')->first();
```

**Update:**

```
TblModel::where('date', TblModel::max('date'))->orderBy('date','desc')->get();
```

Comment: but it will only fetch one record.
What if on same date and time there are multiple records?
How can you tackle that?

Comment: @SizzlingCode use `->get()` instead of using `->first()`

Comment: No, It will list everything in date descending order, 
what i meant for last datetime if there are multiple records, only for that specific last datetime how you get multiple records?

Comment: @SizzlingCode thanks for noticing, see my updated code

Answer (score 11):

### You can use `latest()`:

```
DB::table('tbl')->latest()->first(); // considers created_at field by default.
```

#### Or

```
DB::table('items')->latest('date')->first(); //specify your own column
```

---

**Under the hood:**

`latest()` will `orderBy` with the column you provide in `descending` order where the default column will be `created_at`.

```
//Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder
public function latest($column = 'created_at')
{
    return $this->orderBy($column, 'desc');
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can also use an [Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) here for your query

```
TableModel::latest()->first(); // returns the latest inserted record

TableModel::oldest()->first(); // returns the first ever inserted record from your table
```

Answer (score -3):

This is well documented here:

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#retrieving-single-models

> You may also use the `count`, `sum`, `max`, and other aggregate methods provided by the query builder. These methods return the appropriate scalar value instead of a full model instance:

Examples:

```
$max = DB::table('tbl')::max('date');
$max = App\TblModel::where('active', 1)->max('date');
```

As described already, you do not necessarily need an Model for this using the `DB::table` syntax.

What you should also may want to consider is the [performance aspect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/426785/2427579) of your provided answers here (in case you do not use an index on that column at least)

Comment: who is downvoting without any comment?

Comment: Sure, I added the example just 1 minute afterwards. Immediate downvoting in this manner is worth thinking about!

Comment: Background: I added this comment from my mobile first, then it took some seconds to paste the example. Now on my desktop I'm thinking about the friendly guys used the chance to downvote before I wanted to add even more details on my desktop. As I said, that's kind of impolite.