# MySQL - Find the lowest unique value in table

Tags: mysql

So I have a table for biddings, you can win the bidding by posting the lowest unique bid. So if 2 people place a bet of `$1`, none of them win, if 1 person places a bet of `$2`, this guy wins. But how can I check this in MySQL?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to learn how to write effective questions. Maybe add some example

Comment: errr https://www.ebay.com ?

Comment: It's for a school task, I tried to search it myself, but I couldn't find some an answer of possibility. I was thinking to put it in a for loop in my php to find the unique value, but I was wondering if there was a solution in mySQL. DISTINCT() doesn't work on this.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426731/min-max-vs-order-by-and-limit

Comment: I find it hard to believe you've tried looking for yourself. I copy/pasted and googled the title of your question and came up with multiple answers on Stackoverflow in under 60 seconds.

Comment: Maybe it's just a `GROUP BY bet` with a `HAVING COUNT(*) = 1`  and `ORDER BY bet ASC LIMIT 1`. Then get the `MAX(bidder)` from that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your table has the bid value stored in the field name `bet`, then below is a *worked* solution:

```
SELECT * FROM YourTableName
WHERE bet = (SELECT MIN(bet) FROM YourTableName)
GROUP BY bet
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

Comment: you should **always** explain your code to help OP understand the issue and solution to help develop their skillset :)

Comment: So I found the correct solution, thanks for the feedback!
Ass you can see, I have two tables, one with the auctions, one with the biddings

`SELECT auction.auction_id, bid.price, bid.auction_id, auction.* FROM auction
INNER JOIN bid on auction.auction_id = bid.auction_id
WHERE auction.auction_id = 2
GROUP BY bid.price
HAVING COUNT(bid.price)<2 ORDER BY price ASC limit 1`