# How could I get the lowest value from a mysqli result?

Tags: php, mysqli

So currently I am trying to get the lowest time from a column in mysql (the time is an int) to make a queue system if you can call it that.

However I was struck with a problem that lead me back here. The problem arises when instead of the lowest time value, I get the lowest type value (also an INT)

currently I use `php mysqli_fetch_array()` to get an array from the result so I can then use `php min()`

```php
if (isset($_GET['type'])) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM render_queue WHERE type=?');
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['type']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result=$stmt->get_result();
    $row= mysqli_fetch_array($result);
    echo min($row['date_submit']);
    exit();
}
```

The exit is there so I can see what gets returned.

This should be outputting the lowest time from the database but instead outputs the lowest type from the row. Any help I can get is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What about using `ORDER BY columnname ASC`?

Comment: That could get me the highest time value from the row?

Comment: Well, use `DESC'` then

Comment: hey I think I got it! thank you @SujeetAgrahari !

Comment: Probably worth looking at using `MIN(date_submit)` as it doesn't need to sort the records to then just take the last item (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426731/min-max-vs-order-by-and-limit gives a fuller explanation).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to do `ORDER BY date_submit ASC LIMIT 1`

```
if (isset($_GET['type'])) {
    $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM render_queue WHERE type=? ORDER BY  date_submit ASC LIMIT 1');
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_GET['type']);
    $stmt->execute();
    $result=$stmt->get_result();
    $row= mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);
    echo $row['date_submit'];
    exit();
}
```